# How does asp.net mvc3 instantiate client side validation?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

This question most closely relates to the asp.net mvc3 framework. It started out as "How can I ensure active validation for dynamically appended input fields using jQuery with asp.net mvc3?" However, after some searching, testing, and coffee I came across this:

```
function reValidate(formId) {
 $("#" + formId).removeData("validator");
 $("#" + formId).removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
 $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#" + formId);
}
```

This works just fine. However, I am more curious about the mechanism that the framework is actually using. I have a page which is entirely generated based on a script. The only thing in the view is a `<div>`, a `<script>` tag to load my library, and another `<script>` to populate the `<div>`. After rendering an entirely dynamic page, the validation is flawless. However, if the same process which was used when the page loads is used after the page was loaded to include some new content then the validation breaks. Sure, just call `reValidate()`.

But -

**a) How does the framework instantiate the validation once the page has loaded (or as it loads)?**

**b) Which part of the framework handles it? Is it the mvc3 part, the asp.net part, the razor engine, or another part?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> a) How does the framework instantiate the validation once the page has
>   loaded (or as it loads)?

It parses the DOM, looks for `data-*` attributes on your input fields and adds the [jquery.validate rules](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules). jQuery validate is a client side validation plugin which has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC and could be used with any server side framework or even with plain static HTML.

> b) Which part of the framework handles it? Is it the mvc3 part, the
>   asp.net part, the razor engine, or another part?

It's the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` script. The ASP.NET MVC helpers such as `Html.TextBoxFor` simply use the model metadata to generate input fields with the proper `data-*` attributes based on data annotations you used for your model. Those attributes contain all the necessary information in order to generate the native jquery validate rules. So the unobtrusive script makes the glue between the ASP.NET MVC Model metadata and the `jquery.validate` plugin. It's the `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse` function that does this job. That's the reason why you need to manually invoke it when you modify dynamically the DOM - you are adding/removing `data-*` attributes that need to be translated into jquery validate rules. Don't hesitate to look at how it is implemented inside `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`.

Comment: Thank you for the as always high quality answer. One of the reasons I was curious about this was due to an inconsistent validation message for a dropdown. The message would not go away when an option was selected. By looking through the `unobtrusive.js` file I was able to find `$(selector).valid()` which will re-evaluate an input and was able to incorporate that into part of my solution. Thanks again!

Comment: Any link related to this topic for asp.net mvc 2?

Answer (score 2):

It works as described by Darin Dimitrov in his answer, on the client side, on the server side the mvc rendering engine uses the metadata provided for the model (usually the attributes we put on the properties of our model classes) to decide which data is needed for the data-* attributes, and if they should be rendered at all. 

If you are interested in a more precise answer, you can always look at the [source code of mvc 3](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781), to see exactly when and how the metadata is read by the html helper methods, which eventually create the html string for you.